# how to create a separate class on android studio

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio

I know it's basic to all of you but I want to learn every part of it.

So my question is how can I create a separate class with the operation(plus, minus, multiply, divide) inside.

It is just a quick sample code so don't mind if its awful. The point is I want to see how can you call an operation on other class. Thank you in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button Plus,Minus,Multiply,Divide;
    EditText EditTextfirst,EditTextsecond,EditTextresult;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditTextfirst = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstnumber); // reference to the address
        EditTextsecond = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondnumber); // reference to the address
        EditTextresult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3); // reference to the address
        Plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus); // reference to the connect button
        Minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus); // reference to the connect button
        Multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiply); // reference to the connect button
        Divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide); // reference to the connect button

        Plus.setOnClickListener(PlusOnClickListener);
        Minus.setOnClickListener(MinusOnClickListener);
        Multiply.setOnClickListener(MultiplyOnClickListener);
        Divide.setOnClickListener(DivideOnClickListener);


    }

    View.OnClickListener PlusOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            int x;
            int a,b;
            //String a = EditTextfirst.getText().toString();
            //String b = EditTextsecond.getText().toString();
            a = Integer.parseInt(EditTextfirst.getText().toString());
            b = Integer.parseInt(EditTextsecond.getText().toString());

            if(EditTextfirst != null && EditTextsecond != null  ){

                x = a+b;
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
    };


    View.OnClickListener MinusOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            int x;
            int a,b;

            a = Integer.parseInt(EditTextfirst.getText().toString());
            b = Integer.parseInt(EditTextsecond.getText().toString());

            if(EditTextfirst != null && EditTextsecond != null  ){

                x = a-b;
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener MultiplyOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            int x;
            int a,b;

            a = Integer.parseInt(EditTextfirst.getText().toString());
            b = Integer.parseInt(EditTextsecond.getText().toString());

            if(EditTextfirst != null && EditTextsecond != null  ){

                x = a*b;
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
    };
    View.OnClickListener DivideOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            int x;
            int a,b;

            a = Integer.parseInt(EditTextfirst.getText().toString());
            b = Integer.parseInt(EditTextsecond.getText().toString());

            if(EditTextfirst != null && EditTextsecond != null  ){

                x = a/b;
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: You make an object to call a method of another class. If it is a utility class, you define the methods as static and call them directly with the class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you properly, you want to create a utility class for your methods:

You make an object to call a method of another class. If it is a utility class, you define the methods as static and call them directly with the class name.

Example:

```
    class A {

       public static method1(){
         //do something
       }

    }


    class B{
       public static void main(){
         A.method1();
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class(Util), add function(SampleFunc) with `public static`, call it in activities by Util.SampleFunc. That's quite simple.